# Does breaking large combinational logic into small logic really reduce the delay?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to understand my friend's verilog design, he broke the large logic into small logic, he said it helped him fixed the timing issue. But I don't understand why, because after synthesis, those are just bunch of AND and OR gates, and the logic is the same, how could this reduce the delay? 
Here's the original code:

```
    assign state0 = ({104{d0_xq}} & markerState0[519:416]) | 
                ({104{d1_xq}} & markerState1[519:416]) |
                ({104{d2_xq}} & markerState2[519:416]) |
                ({104{d3_xq}} & markerState3[519:416]);

assign state1 = ({104{d0_xq}} & markerState0[415:312]) |
                ({104{d1_xq}} & markerState1[415:312]) |
                ({104{d2_xq}} & markerState2[415:312]) |
                ({104{d3_xq}} & markerState3[415:312]);

assign state2 = ({104{d0_xq}} & markerState0[311:208]) |
                ({104{d1_xq}} & markerState1[311:208]) |
                ({104{d2_xq}} & markerState2[311:208]) |
                ({104{d3_xq}} & markerState3[311:208]);

assign state3 = ({104{d0_xq}} & markerState0[207:104]) |
                ({104{d1_xq}} & markerState1[207:104]) |
                ({104{d2_xq}} & markerState2[207:104]) |
                ({104{d3_xq}} & markerState3[207:104]);

assign state4 = ({104{d0_xq}} & markerState0[103:0]) |
                ({104{d1_xq}} & markerState1[103:0]) |
                ({104{d2_xq}} & markerState2[103:0]) |
                ({104{d3_xq}} & markerState3[103:0]);

always @(posedge clock) begin
    state_xq <= {state0, state1, state2, state3, state4};  
end
```

What is the difference if I use:

```
assign state = ({520{d0_xq}} & markerState0) |
                ({520{d1_xq}} & markerState1) |
                ({520{d2_xq}} & markerState2) |
                ({520{d3_xq}} & markerState3);
always @(posedge clock) begin
    state_xq <= state;  
end
```

Comment: If you're using Xilinx, I suggest looking at the schematic output of both and comparing. Other than that, it would be difficult to tell if either would result in different synthesis. I'm not sure how else you'd find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is some sort of ASIC technology You can dig into the generated netlist and check if for some reason different primitives were used and hence different timing is achieved even though logically both structures give the same result. Either way this is strange and I'd not expect to see significant divergence in STA results but I'm not an expert on synthesis engines tho.

Alternatively tool should allow You to generate reg-2-reg report showing exact breakdown of the path, this should reveal where tool applies different approach (e.g. on which operation).